# How to delete entries after uninstalling softwares

Tags: filesystem, system

After un-istalling a particular software, the entries created by the specific software during its use will be in place even after un-istallation. The entries i talk here about the hidden files present in the Home folder under the name "." folder.

My question is

1. Even the size of the files are very few KBs, how do these files could be deleted easily?
2. If we won't delete these folders and once again install the same software, does there a high probability of using the same old entries in the software no?
3. I had observed that after subsequent up gradations the 'Dot file/hidden file' entries increases when some of the softwares are de-faulty installed wth fresh installations. So is there some way to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are for configurations. You can delete them which means that if you re-install the software you will have the default instead of yours previous configuration.

1) To delete them:
  - Open nautilus (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `nautilus`), 
  - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show the hidden files, 
  - Right click over the folder to delete, 
  - Choose "Move to Trash"

[image]

2) Yes, the configuration will be used.

3) Yes, as referred in "1".

Comment: # Wellcome :-) #